# Why is my JavaScript Twitter feed not working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, twitter

We're rolling out a redesign of helpcurenow.org, and we've implemented a Twitter feed in the footer. (I'm the design & front end guy, my coworker is the scripting & backend guy).

All is well with the Twitter feed in all major browsers except internet explorer, version 8 and later.

However we have no clue why IE is not pulling the feed at all. Any hints??

http://betawww.helpcurenow.org/
(look in footer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! The problem is with the `li.innerHTML =` assignment. Basically, you're feeding the Twitter script a template somewhere, which looks like

```
"<li class="ftr-tweet"><p>%text%</p><a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%" class="ftr-tweetTimestamp">%time%</a></li>"
```

But unfortunately, Twitter already created a `<li>` and only wants to get its **inner** HTML. What happens now is that you insert a `<li>` into the Twitter-created `<li>`... which most browsers accept, but IE8 doesn't. It simply won't accept incorrect HTML, which is of course a very noble principle for Microsoft. See http://www.theogray.com/blog/2009/06/internet-explorer-unknown-runtime-error.

So the solution is leaving the li out of your template. But then you won't have the `ftr-tweet` class anymore... So replace it with a `<span>` and all's well with the world.

```
"<span class="ftr-tweet"><p>%text%</p><a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%" class="ftr-tweetTimestamp">%time%</a></span>"
```

Comment: I must admit I really do like IE8's Debugger Tools, which helped me find the issue here. Of course, they're nothing compared to Firebug, but still very useful. So, when can I see the page work correctly? ;)

Comment: 18 minutes...that was impressive my friend.

Comment: we just changed it locally, so as soon as we push our current changes live. Later today. thanks again!

Comment: OK, I see it works fine. One unrelated layout suggestion: the top menu "slide open" buttons are *really* small and hard to hit. Any possibility of changing that? ;)